# Как убрать форму в HTML через PHP?

Tags: php, html

Здравствуйте ! Есть допустим html файл с содержанием, который подключен через php

```
<body>
<div class="#">Шапка</div>
[form] 
<div class="#">Форма входа</div>
[/form]
</body>
```

Как сделать так что-бы внутри [form] [/form] форма исчезала ?

То есть если пользователь вошел на сайт то скрыть форму, а если не вошел, то показать !
Код должен быть на php !
Спасибо заранее !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно например регуляркой:

```
$html = preg_replace('#<form(.*?)>(.*?)</form>#is', '', $html);
```

А по хорошему вам подключить шаблонизатор надо.

Answer (score 0):

Это можно сделать так:
При входе повесить $_SESSION['login'] - если пользователь вошел.
На странице(в меню) поставить условие

```
<?php if(!isset($_SESSION['login'])){
echo '<div class=#>Форма входа</div>';
}?>
```